# When i pass one form id to the queryselectorall method im able to see all the inputs inside the form

Tags: javascript

When i pass one form id to the queryselectorall method im able to see all the inputs inside the form. But when i pass two id of form to queryselector all i see it two form being returned. Can some one help me out with this ? Below is the code that im using

```
window.$ = function(el) {
    el = document.querySelectorAll(el);
    el.size = el.length;
  if (el.length === 1) {
   el[0].size = 1;
   return el[0];
} else {
  return el;
}
```

};

Complete Code:

```
window.onload=function(){
(function (window) {
    window.Q = function (el) {

        el = document.querySelectorAll(el);
        el.size = el.length;

        if (el.length === 1) {
            el[0].size = 1;
            return el[0];
        } else {
            return el;
        }
    };

    window.addEvents = function (el, ev, fn) {
        var i,
        el = (typeof el == 'string') ? Q(el) : el,
            ev = (ev.indexOf(' ')) ? ev.split(' ') : [ev];

        ev.forEach(function (ea) {
            if (el.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                    el[i].addEventListener(ea, fn, false);
                }
            } else {
                console.log(el, ea, fn)
                el.addEventListener(ea, fn, false);
            }
        });
    };
    window.callme = function (e) {
        console.log(e.type)
    }
    window.init = function () {
        /*Below code works when i bind events to one form and all the input fields gets the events attached */
        //window.addEvents('#form1', 'focus keyup blur', callme);
    /* Uncomment the below line to reproduce the issue only the key up event gets fired and that is also getting attached to form and not to form elements*/
        window.addEvents('#form1,#form2', 'focus keyup blur', callme);
    }

})(window);
window.init();
```

Comment: What are you passing when you call your function?  Perhaps [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) can help you understand how `querySelectorAll()` works.

Comment: Well, if only one element is selected, you are returning it, while if more than one are selected you are returning the node list instead. It's not clear to me what *" im able to see all the inputs inside the form"* means and it is not clear what your problem actually is.

Answer (score 0):

http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp6a

```
$("#form1 input, #form2 input");
```

**Edits:** 
I modified your question and included code you have written in fiddle.

Now the problem here is not selector but its about event bubbling.

Events blur & focus are not bubbling event. so they don't bubble up and go to its parent.
you must attache those events to element itselt.

You might want to have a look at **focusin, focusout** events which are bubling equivalent of blur & focus. but very few browsers are supporting it.

framework like jquery, dojo has focusin, focusout events implemented which are good for all browsers. you can have a look at how they have implemented those.

Comment: Here is the exact implementation what im trying to do. i'm building my own library and where i want addEvents to work exactly like how it wokrs in jquery or other libraries. im not sure where im going wrong. i was thinking something is wrong with the selector. now im not sure if im wrong with addevents method that i wrote. 

here is the complete code snippet that i wrote.

Comment: Here is the fiddle link which helps in understanding better
http://jsfiddle.net/WBDPY/10/

Comment: explanation modified based on the link.